# How to create messages if condition is True in django?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am working on authentication webapp and I want to display message if user input doesn't match some conditions. It should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTUwO.png).

For example: if password has length less than 8 characters then display message 'Password should be longer than 8 characters!'

**My view:**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        context = {'has_error': False,
        'data': request.POST,
        'length_error': False,
        'password_match_error': False,
        'validate_email_error': False,
        }
        global password
        global password2
        global email
        global username
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        password2 = request.POST.get('password2')

        if len(password) < 8:
                ############custom message
                context['length_error'] = True

        if password != password2:
            ############custom message
            context['password_match_error'] = True

        if not validate_email(email):
            ############custom message
            context['validate_email_error'] = True

        if not username:
            ############custom message
            context['has_error'] = True

        if models.CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'This email is already registered!')
            context['has_error'] = True

            return render(request, 'authentication/signup.html', context, status=409)
        if context['has_error']:
            return render(request, 'authentication/signup.html', context)

        body = render_to_string('authentication/email/email_body.html', {
            'username': username,
            'token': token,
        })
        send_mail(
            "Email Confirmation",
            body,
            'tadejtilinger@gmail.com',
            [email]
        )
        return redirect('email-confirmation')
    return render(request, 'authentication/signup.html')
```

**My signup.html**

```
{% include  "_base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/authentication/signup.css' %}">
<div class="container">
  <form class="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'signup' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="input_1" name="email" value="{{ data.email }}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="input_2" name="username" value="{{ data.username }}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Password" class="input_3" name="password" value="{{ data.password }}">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Confirm password" class="input_4" name="password2" value="{{ data.password2 }}">
    <button type="submit" class="submit_btn1">Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>
{% block scripts %}
<script src="js/signup.js"></script>
{% endblock scripts %}
{% endblock content %}
```

My signup.js is empty.
If you want me to post anything else just comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing those error variables into your context so you can just render them in your template, you can do something like this:

```
{% if length_error %}
<p>Your password must be longer than 8 characters</p>
{% endif %}
```

But for all of your different errors. Django has a login form inbuilt which validates for this kind of thing, I would suggest using that rather than re-inventing the wheel.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work. I think it's because when I click submit button just then I get information about errors.

Comment: That's because your code always redirects to email confirmation, if you have errors you should render the signup page again

Comment: now I did it and it works... kinda... it doesn't redirect to email_confirmation but it still doesn't show message even if I write if statement like you did up there

Comment: Make sure you are passing your `context` to render: `return render(request, 'authentication/signup.html', context)`